# Not able to perform a search on integer field type with surround query parser in Solr

Tags: solr

I have a requirement to perform a Solr search with surround query parser where I am performing search on string and integer type fields

ex: [http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/testcollection/select?q={!surround](http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/testcollection/select?q=%7B!surround) (content:abc) AND (size:1199)

where content field is of type string and size is of type integer.

I do not get any result when queries against size (integer).

I am sure, I have the matching documents for the above query.

I tried looking into the internal implementation of the surround query parser and looks like SrndTermQuery is used to form the query. I want to understand the part where surround parser handles the integer field types.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this? The surround query parser looks for terms _in close proximity_ to each other _inside a token stream_. There is no proximity across fields, and you only have a single term given for the content field - so what is your end goal?

Comment: okay, suppose I have a query
q={!surround}(content:(10w(term1,term2))) AND size:1199

The query does not fetch results against the size field even if I have documents with size 1199. size if of type int.

And also I think, even if we query for single term, it returns the results.

Comment: Also, when I used other string fields in place of size, I was getting the results.

Comment: Use a filter query for the `size:1199` part. `q={!surround}content:(10w(term1,term2))&fq=size:1199`. This will also be generally also be more performant as the result of the fq can be cached separately.

Comment: yes, this will definitely work. I wanted to understand why surround doesn't let us query on numeric fields. The standard and the edismax parsers internally transforms a numeric field query into a range query. Can I do something to get the surround parser working on numeric fields?

Comment: I'm guessing its because their not regularly tokenized fields (and can contain multiple values for a single field). Another guess is that there might be differences based on _what kind of numeric field you've defined_ (i.e. point based vs legacy vs trie, etc.). Might want to ask on the `solr-user` for more details. You can index the field as a regular string field if you want to include it with the surround parser, and use a separate field for range filtering.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much for all the information.